# Remove leading comma from FOR XML PATH function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a variable that accepts multiple string values using the `FOR XML PATH`:

```
  set @Control_Number = 

   (SELECT DISTINCT 
      SUBSTRING(
    (
        SELECT ''', '''+ co.control_number  AS [text()]
        FROM #AGBCaseCompanyMap2 co
        WHERE co.company_id = co2.company_id                       
        ORDER BY co.company_id
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 2, 1000) [control_number]
```

The result I'm getting is including a leading comma: (', '0045', '4343').
I've used the `STUFF` function in the past to remove this but I can't figure out how to use it here.  I keep getting errors like "`STUFF` function requires 4 values."  Does anyone know how to remove that leading quote and comma?

Comment: One method is with `STUFF`(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax/207380#207380) for deails of using `XML PATH` for aggregate string concatenation.

Comment: If you're on SQL 2017 or later try [string_agg()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql), e.g.: `select string_agg(quotename(name, ''''), ',') within group (order by name) from sys.objects`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the quotes separately with `STUFF` in the query:

```
set @Control_Number = 

   (SELECT DISTINCT 
      STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ', '+ '''' + co.control_number + '''' AS [text()]
        FROM #AGBCaseCompanyMap2 co
        WHERE co.company_id = co2.company_id                       
        ORDER BY co.company_id
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 2, '') [control_number]
```